# Railstutorial.org: Stuck in 9.2.2 (requiring the right user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

All of the tests at the end of chapter 9.2.1 (requiring signed-in users) passed for me.  But my tests at the end of chapter 9.2.2 (requiring the right user) fail.  In fact, there are 21 failures.

My source code is at https://github.com/jhsu802701/ror-sample/tree/updating-users .

The list of error messages is TOO long to print out in full here, but I've uploaded them to my GitHub repository for this project at https://raw.github.com/jhsu802701/ror-sample/updating-users/ERRORS-9_2_2.txt .

All of the tests at the end of chapter 9.2.1 passed.  At the end of chapter 9.2.2, there were 21 failures.  I've gone through 9.2.2 multiple times, but I'm still getting the 21 errors.  So I'm guessing that I must have made the error earlier on, but that error didn't become relevant until 9.2.2.  (I had a problem in chapter 8 that was due to a mistake I made in chapter 5 that didn't become relevant until 3 chapters later.  I only figured out how to fix it because somebody else who had the same problem posted here on StackOverflow.)

EDIT: Uploaded a copy of the error messages IN FULL and provided a link to them.

Comment: can you put the first few lines of the error message up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just been through the tutorial myself so I hope that some of what I experienced can help you :-)

Based on the error which you are getting:

Failure/Error: sign_in user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `current_user=' for #

I think you are missing this from your SessionsHelper module:

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end
```

This function should be there so we can indicate who the current user is

HTH,
Nathan

Comment: Thanks, Nathan.  This worked.  I didn't realize that the def current_user statement in listing 9.16 was only a supplement and not a replacement for the section you cited.